# Vuejs initialize a global dictionary and access it from other components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Consider the (very rough) outline of my SPA 
(I am posting only small portion of code):

It is a simple crud SPA that displays a table of entries and allows user to edit / delete / create table entries.

**router index.js**

```
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Start',
      component: Start
    }, 
    {
      path: '/table',
      name: 'Table',
      component: Table,
      props: false
    },
     {
      path: '/addEntry',
      name: 'AddEntry',
      component: AddEntry,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})
```

App.vue

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

What I want is to declare a variable `dictionary` (a map) inside App so that it will be available to all components (Start, Table, AddEntry) but also to the components used by this components (e.g. in my case `Table` also uses  `TableHeader` and  `Tablerow`).

The idea is to fill this map (using `axios` `get`) with `json` map sent from server side ({value : description}) and then use it for displaying descriptions instead of ids in `Table` and `AddEntry` components.

So the question I have is: where  the call to `axios` `get` must go to initialize my map, and then how to access that map from all of my components.

Thanks.

P.S. For the development I am using `npm` (`.vue` components etc.)

Comment: Have a look at Vuex, it's for state management and will hold your variables for you globally.

Comment: @Styphon ok thanks